# How to cycle a single div in an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am trying to see if the following is possible:

[image: single rotating div]

I want to be able to cycle a single div within an element continuously [so the start of the div is by the end of the same div as it cycles.]

This doesn't have to be an existing plugin. I would prefer to not clone the div if possible. The div's width will be set via javascript prior to cycle but might be adjusted in small amounts.

I would appreciate any ideas!

Comment: +1 for the gif :D You cannow expect to see part of the newcoming element without cloning it.

Comment: I don't believe this to be possible without cloning the div.

Comment: You need to clone the element.

Comment: 1) Clone. 2) Animate. 3) Remove orignal. 4) ??? 5) profit...?

Comment: Thanks all, I will take a look into how much of a problem cloning will bring. Glad you like the gif :P

Comment: @Neurofluxation c'mon... it's all about profit! ;)

Comment: @BorisKourt You need the dynamic contents of the div to animate, yes? Perhaps being clearer, you would be able to scroll an image like that with background position and horizontal repeat

Comment: @MaxPRafferty also a great suggestion.

Comment: unfortunately this div contains a lot of dynamic elements that I would rather not rotate or cycle through due to the way they are arranged. So I just want to see if there is an interesting way to get the whole div to rotate within an element, without having to duplicate it and its contents.

Comment: You may be able to do this in the future (or now in browsers that support it) using the canvas element to render the contents of your div pixel by pixel as is done in: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ and then either store the result in a matrix and loop, or render a gif on the fly from it as is done in: http://emergent.unpythonic.net/software/01126462511-glif ...though that is admittedly not really cleaner than cloning the element, heh.

Comment: Thanks, I just stumbled on this exact library as well :D Luckily for me I have complete control over which browser and device displays it, so I might test it out. But it does seem terribly excessive haha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ogetoh/8/edit)*

jQuery:

```
$('.scroller').each(function(){
  $(this).find('img').clone().appendTo($(this));
});

(function move(){
  $('.scroller').scrollLeft(0).stop().animate({scrollLeft:310},800,'linear',move);
})();
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="scroller">
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.scroller{
  width:310px;
  height:80px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  word-spacing:-1em;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:30px;
}
.scroller img{
  display:inline; 
}
```

It will make clones only once. Than my jQuery script will create a loop that will just play with the `scrollLeft()` element property.

N.B: this is just a plain example, you could make `310px` be dynamically calculated, but that's another story, let's keep it simple.

Comment: @BorisKourt You're welcome! here is a demo with DIV as children http://jsbin.com/ogetoh/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

What about the marquee plugin?

[Demo](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html)
[Docs](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/)

Note that first example in the Demo, that scrolls left, if you set the width of the container to the same size or smaller than your content to scroll it will appear to cycle fluidly.

Comment: That div actually has to completely go off screen before it is repositioned back for another round. It seems that there is no choice but to clone the element.

Comment: Hmm thinking about it -... my brain now hurts. Really not sure if it'll be possible without duplication. Another solution that relies on duplication just incase you want to try it with duplication: http://jsfiddle.net/xRcwH/

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that cloning is the only way. Unless it is possible to mirror the element via some kind of transform [think reflections] but usually even that is cloning. [It doesn't have to be clickable or interactive.]