# Rotate same div from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have one div which contains some canvas & images and all.

Now what i want to do is, i want to rotate this div but when div moves left to right at the same time that same div start showing from left.

Some thing like it just effect nothing more then that.

i have tried using 2 div, it works well but its tedious to manage how can i do it using 1 div?

here is my code.

```
$('#main').swipeleft(function( event ) {
     $('#test').animate({ 'left': window.innerWidth }, 1,function(){
           $('#main').animate({"left": -width}, "fast", function(){});
           $('#test').animate({"left": -width}, "fast", function(){});
     });
});
```

here main & test are two divs.

Here is HTML (its simple)

```
<div class="whiteBackground" id="main" style="position: relative;">
            <img src="img1" style="z-index: 1; top:0px;" height="200px" width="200px">
            </img>
        </div>
<div class="whiteBackground" id="test" style="position: relative;">
            <img src="img1" style="z-index: 1; top:0px;" height="200px" width="200px">
            </img>
        </div>
```

please help me out.

Comment: `{"left": -width}` where's `width` variable here??

Comment: Did you set the float: right? So you can move to the left? Or atleast a margin-left?

Comment: its window.innerWidth

Comment: some HTML and CSS pls

Comment: i want this same img1 in rotation but i dont know how to do so.

Comment: CSS! `transform:rotate(90deg);`

Comment: share it in jsfiddler.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this answer - [How to cycle a single div in an element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200484/how-to-cycle-a-single-div-in-an-element-with-jquery)

it seems to do what you want, without any extra plugins

Comment: Thanks this is what i actually want.

Answer (score 0):

with this plugins you can rotate easily !
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/5-jquery-spinrotate-image-plugins-demos/

Answer (score 0):

Refer this SO Answer, You have two ways to achieve it.

1. Using jQuery Plugin `jqueryrotate`
2. Using CSS Transform

URL: [jquery rotate image onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365449/jquery-rotate-image-onclick)